# How to update auto layout constraints in SubClass of UIView on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I created a `UIView` subclass and added some imageViews and labels in it. I used Visual Format to create `constraints`. And the view layout is different for different size class. I used below code to identify the size class.

```
let rule = UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .regular)
let isHorizontalRegular = self.traitCollection.containsTraits(in: rule)
if isHorizontalRegular {
// constraints for  Horizontal Regular size class
} else {
// constraints for  other size class
}
```

Since I was not getting the size class information in `init` method so I created all the auto layout `constraints` are created in `updateConstraints()` method.

Based on this implementation I'm have some questions.

1. Is it correct approach to create all the `constraint` in overridden method `updateConstraints()`?
2. If not, which is the west way to create auto layout `constraints` based on size class.
3. How can I update the auto layout `constraints` on orientation change.(since i'm using visual format to create auto layout `constraints`)?

I know I can solve my problem using `UIViewController` life cycle method. But I'm using `@IBDesignable` to render the View on storyboard. So is it possible to achieve these within `UIView` subclass.

Please help me to solve these questions.

Comment: Have you looked in to or used the override `didLayoutSubviews`?

Answer (score 0):

Careful, some links continuing Obj-C coming up.

The first step is to learn the entire view life cycle, [this should help](https://rdkw.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/ios-uiviewcontroller-lifecycle/). The next step is to understand what [adaptive layout](http://imnotyourson.com/ios-adaptive-layout-with-rotation-tips/) is.

Focus on these overrides:

**viewDidLoad():**
This is where you can set up your constraints. Make sure the subviews are loaded and that translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is false for everything.

**viewWillLayoutSubviews():**
I tend to do my orientation changes here, but only because I need to know if the overall bounds is portrait (height>width) or landscape (width>height). You sound like you have a better place....

**viewWillTransition(to size: with coordinator:):**
This is where **any** size class change will happen - or not. iPad slide out or split view also. Just beware, basic iPad orientation change **will not** mean a size class change, as they are regular/regular. Still, this function will be pinged.

Here's a template of what I usually do:

```
var p = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var l = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var initialOrientation = true
var isInPortrait = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpConstraints()
}    

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if initialOrientation {
        initialOrientation = false
        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            isInPortrait = false
        } else {
            isInPortrait = true
        }
        orientationChanged()
    } else {
        if view.orientationHasChanged(&isInPortrait) {
            orientationChanged()
        }
    }
}
func setUpConstraints() {
    view.turnOffAutoResizing()
    // append your portrait (p) and landscape (l) constraint arrays here
}

extension UIView {

    public func turnOffAutoResizing() {
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        for view in self.subviews as [UIView] {
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
    }
    public func orientationHasChanged(_ isInPortrait:inout Bool) -> Bool {
        if self.frame.width > self.frame.height {
            if isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = false
                return true
            }
        } else {
            if !isInPortrait {
                isInPortrait = true
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    public func setOrientation(_ p:[NSLayoutConstraint], _ l:[NSLayoutConstraint]) {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(l)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(p)
        if self.bounds.width > self.bounds.height {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(l)
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(p)
        }
    }
}
```

This is probably a bit of overkill for your needs but you should be able to get the gist of it.